# Theme detection in project properties fails after theme save in GUI Builder

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I have been working with GUI Builder in NetBeans and now when I save any changes in the theme, project properties do not show the theme selected. Anytime I do git reset --hard and check project properties, the theme resource file is selected. Any help?

Hello, 
The exception below shows when I click on save in the GUI Builder even without changing anything in there. The resource and main form entry in project properties are blank. codenameone_settings.properties entries are correct for 
guiResource=theme.res
mainForm=Main
libraries are up to date

``  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.readMultiImage(Resources.java:1083)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.readMultiImage(Resources.java:1056)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.createImage(Resources.java:1038)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.createImage(Resources.java:948)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:296)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:260)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.(Resources.java:181)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:751)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:675)
    [catch] at com.codename1.CodeName1CustomizerTab.createCategory(CodeName1CustomizerTab.java:203)
    at    org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer$DelegateCategoryProvider.readCategories(ProjectCustomizer.java:672)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer$DelegateCategoryProvider.getSubCategories(ProjectCustomizer.java:633)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.ProjectCustomizer.createCustomizerDialog(ProjectCustomizer.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:131)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:108)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.ui.customizer.CustomizerProviderImpl.showCustomizer(CustomizerProviderImpl.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.CustomizeProject$1$1.run(CustomizeProject.java:160)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the migration wizard from the old GUI builder to the new GUI builder? This would effectively disable the GUI builder.

Are the entries disabled or just blank?

Look in the `codenameone_settings.properties` for the project. You should see two entries:

```
guiResource=theme.res
mainForm=Main
```

Make sure they match the file name and the main form you have available. Also make sure your plugin and libraries are up to date.

Assuming all of the above is correct, check the version of your IDE plugin and look within the IDE log to see if there are any exceptions that occur when you open the project preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There was an image which was changed into a multi image. I realized the files in the multi image folder were missing. That was the cause of the issue.